# display list in select html in function of another select choice in a jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, select, jstl

I don't know if my title is well understanding, but what i want to do it's to display a list in option of a select element depending of the choice of another select element. I'm using this with a jsp page and with a Map variable to have the differents lists.

The jsp page look like this:

```
<form:select id="typeIndice1" path="typeIndice"  itemLabel="libelle" onchange="run()">
        <form:options items="${listeIndices}" />
    </form:select>


<form:select id="indices" path="indice" itemValue="valeur" itemLabel="libelle" >
        </form:select>
```

The model attribute is "listeIndices" which is a Map with key, the data to display on the second select, and value, the wording of the data. I know normally i should do the reverse for the Key, Value but is to display the wording easily on the first select.
I have this script below:

```
<script>
function run(){
    var select = document.getElementById("typeIndice1");
    var input = document.getElementById("indices");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = select.value;
    input.options.add(option);
}
```

When an option is selected on the first select, the run function create a new option to the second select whit the value of the first select, i have the complete list in only one option, but i would like each row in one option but i don't know how to do.

i also tried:

```
option.items = select.value;
```

instead of

```
option.text = select.value;
```

But i have a blank option.

Comment: can you please reform the question properly ?, do you want nested lists where you select one value from the list and accordingly second list changes ?

Comment: yes, this is this. i'm still looking for... but I saw that the "select.value" doesn't return a list but a kind of string. I should have the Map object in js but i don't know how.

Comment: can you post full code here ?